# Can you set more than one password on lock screen for android?

Tags: android

is it possible to set more than one password for the lock screen on Android? If so, what parts of the SDK let you do that?

Comment: if you're gonna down vote at least explain why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to set more than one password for the lock screen on Android?

Not in Android in general. It's entirely possible that some manufacturers have done something like that, but it would be unique to their devices.